# Configuring build path works, but adding same dependency in pom does not

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, soap, jar

So I'm attempting to use org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderInterceptor in one of the modules of my project in Eclipse.

Since this was a new jar that I was adding, I initially downloaded it myself and then added it as a referenced library under the project. All was good. I had my class extend SoapHeaderInterceptor, and everything was hunky dory.

So once I was done coding everything, I removed the jar from the referenced libraries and instead added it to my module's pom like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I did a Maven update on the project, and subsequently saw the jar added under the Maven Dependencies. I even opened up my local m2 repository and it's there as well.

BUT I am now getting errors on the class (shown below)

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends SoapHeaderInterceptor
```

as follows:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor. Fix the
>   build path then try building this project
>
> The type org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files AuthenticationInterceptor.java
>
> The hierarchy of the type AuthenticationInterceptor is inconsistent

Note: SoapHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I am absolutely stumped. I have cleaned/built my workspace multiple times. The module that I added the dependency to actually already has several more dependencies from before, so it's not as though it's not configured for Maven. I see no error on the line that imports the package, so clearly it is finding the jar somewhere (the build path or the m2 repo). I'm using version 2.5.2 of the jar, and I know someone who has used this jar for the exact same purpose in the exact same way, successfully.

The only thing I can think of that could be an issue (could someone confirm?) is that my local m2 repo has multiple versions of this jar, one older and two newer. Could this be causing some sort of conflict?

Edit: On further inspection I see that org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor isn't actually there anywhere in my repo. I have the cxf.interceptor package in cxf-api-2.5.2.jar but it doesn't have this class. Any solutions? Do I have to use a different version of the jar?

Answer (score 1):

If you open your POM in Eclipse and select "Dependency Hierarchy" you should be able to see if another (direct) dependency is interfering or omitting the jar-files you need.

I just tried to retrace your steps with this POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>art1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and created a class:

```
package art1;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderInterceptor;

public class MyClass extends SoapHeaderInterceptor {

}
```

and it compiles just fine. 
Moreover, the class `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor` is present in the same jar and package as `SoapHeaderInterceptor`, so there seems to be something else going on in your environment.

My dependency hierarchy looks like this:

[image: Dependency hierarchy]

Starting from the same dependency, does yours look the same?

Comment: Yes it turned out to be an issue with the cxf-api jar. Even though 2.5.2 was getting added to the maven dependencies, I went through the package structure and found that the AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor class wasn't actually there in the interceptors package. I updated to a later version of both the jars (2.7.6 for the bindings and 2.7.2 for the api) and everything worked out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though 2.5.2 was getting added to the maven dependencies, I went through the package structure and found that the AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor class wasn't actually there in the interceptors package. I updated to a later version of both the jars (2.7.6 for the bindings and 2.7.2 for the api) and everything worked out.